# Android: <Android Studio> My application doesn't work after Android Studio update

Tags: android

My app was working just fine yesterday and now, after updating android studio to 1.32, it does not! It loads on the emulator, but once it's up and running it won't respond or do anything at all. It just stays there frozen. I've searched Stackoverflow for an answer and on the internet in general but I couldn't find anything related to my problem! Please somebody help because I have no idea what might've caused the problem as I haven't changed anything.

My logcat however gives me this:

```
Creating filesystem with parameters:
Size: 69206016
Block size: 4096
Blocks per group: 32768
Inodes per group: 4224
Inode size: 256
Journal blocks: 1024
Label: 
Blocks: 16896
Block groups: 1
Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
emulator: device fd:784
HAXM is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
emulator: warning: opening audio input failed
creating window 61 83 462 820
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
draw: Could not use program error=0x505
draw: Could not use program error=0x505
draw: Could not use program error=0x505
draw: Could not use program error=0x505
draw: Could not use program error=0x505
draw: Could not use program error=0x505
draw: Could not use program error=0x505
draw: Could not use program error=0x505
draw: Could not use program error=0x505
draw: Could not use program error=0x505
draw: Could not use program error=0x505
draw: Could not use program error=0x505
draw: Could not use program error=0x505
ColorBuffer::bindFbo: FBO not complete: 0x8cd6
draw: Could not use program error=0x505
ColorBuffer::bindFbo: FBO not complete: 0x8cd6
ColorBuffer::bindFbo: FBO not complete: 0x8cd6
draw: Could not use program error=0x505
draw: Could not use program error=0x505
ColorBuffer::bindFbo: FBO not complete: 0x8cd6
ColorBuffer::bindFbo: FBO not complete: 0x8cd6
draw: Could not use program error=0x505
draw: Could not use program error=0x505
ColorBuffer::bindFbo: FBO not complete: 0x8cd6
ColorBuffer::bindFbo: FBO not complete: 0x8cd6
draw: Could not use program error=0x505
draw: Could not use program error=0x505
ColorBuffer::bindFbo: FBO not complete: 0x8cd6
ColorBuffer::bindFbo: FBO not complete: 0x8cd6
draw: Could not use program error=0x505
draw: Could not use program error=0x505
ColorBuffer::bindFbo: FBO not complete: 0x8cd6
ColorBuffer::bindFbo: FBO not complete: 0x8cd6
```

I do not know if this is caused from Android Studio update.

Should you require something more, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This is not your code problem. I also faced this. My app is not working in emulator but working fine in phone.
Try once to run app on phone.

Comment: I tried on the phone also but it makes the phone unresponsive as well and sometimes it restarts! It doesn't work on anything and I can't find out why :/ Do you might have a solution to this?